# What plugins are needed to use voice/video chat in empathy?

Tags: video, google-talk

I would like to voice/video chat with google talk contacts in empathy, but the options are disabled.  The help page indicates that this may be due to missing plugins.  What plugins must I install to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

For what I have read and tested here you only need Empathy and to login with a google account. The other user also has to have a google account to make this work.

In the Empathy webpage it says that it supports this features: http://live.gnome.org/Empathy

I would mention the google-talk plugin but thats a browser plugin to use the gtalk features inside the browser.

When you have both users using a google account, the option to **Audio Call** will be highlighted when you right click the user in the Contact List window.

Now to be fair, this was not the case almost a year ago. Back then Empathy did not support this feature. Now you can use Empathy to call a user inside the browser, for example if he or she is using gmail at the moment and has the chat activated.

For now the problem I find is trying to call Empathy from the gmail webpage. It only works from Empathy to Gmail but not the other way around. With the many updates made to Empathy since the last version in Ubuntu 10.04 (Which is the 2.34) am thinking this "bug" might be corrected. For the changelog see here: http://linux.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Empathy-Changelog-27288.html

Comment: I don't get the option on 11.04, but I can video chat the contact just fine from my android phone.

Comment: Just wondering if you happen to update the 11.04. Do you have Empathy 2.34.

Comment: Just to clarify - "When you have both users using a google account" means that both you and the person you want to chat with are voice enabled. That means you might not see the option if they are not able to voice chat, even if the empathy plugin is working... This one caught me out.